# Does solving a NP-hard problem in polynomial time make it NP-complete?

Tags: np, np-complete, np-hard

I am trying to understand the process so that P = NP. Consider a problem L which is reducible to a problem that is NP-Complete, meaning L is NP-hard. Now, if we solve L in polynomial time, will it be NP-complete? Making P = NP to be true. Am I missing something?